# Image saved from webview but not showing in Gallery

Tags: android, download, android-webview, android-download-manager

I  want to download image from `WebView` by long press. The code works smoothly and downloads the image as far i think it saves in cache because whenever i try to open image it vanishes. I want to save permanently image in internal download folder. But if i set

```
   request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir();
```

it crashes.
what to do now?

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        final WebView.HitTestResult result = mWebView.getHitTestResult();
        if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
                result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

            //menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Save Image")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                            String DownloadImageURL = result.getExtra();

                            if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(DownloadImageURL)){

                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadImageURL));
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Image save successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error to save image.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

`LogCat` Output

```
 BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@fe8297a
07-18 15:42:49.964 20572-20572/com.example.aashiq.tonu D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-18 15:42:49.968 20572-20572/com.example.aashiq.tonu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aashiq.tonu, PID: 20572
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/emulated/0/down
        at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:636)
        at com.example.aashiq.tonu.MainActivity$1.onMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:78)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:148)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:166)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$4.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1154)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1164)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3154)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4097)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-18 15:42:50.065 20572-20572/com.example.aashiq.tonu I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20572 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please provide the `LogCat` output of the Exception

Comment: yes I provided that, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a `Permission` problem.

Have you declared the `permission` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Take a look into https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: Yes I declared those

Comment: Did you also implement the Runtime Permissions? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting